# map arrays within arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

im trying to map a rather complex array which looks like this:

```
[
  "Group A",
  ["10/7/2020", "15/7/2020"],
  "Group B",
  ["5/5/2019"],
  "Group C",
  ["3/3/2020", "5/7/2020", "25/7/2020"],
]
```

I am trying to map this array in the render method of react native and display it. Im looking for a result that looks like this:

```
Group A
    10/7/2020
    15/7/2020

Group B
    5/5/2019

Group C
    3/3/2020
    5/7/2020
    25/7/2020
```

How can I do that? thanks

Comment: Where are you trying to render this and what have you tried?

Comment: do you want to convert that array into object?

Answer (score 1):

This is just React, not especially Native, but you'll get the gist.

The idea here is to first mangle the "flat" data into an array of objects `{header: ..., values: ...}` that you can map over as per usual.

```
const data = [
  "Group A",
  ["10/7/2020", "15/7/2020"],
  "Group B",
  ["5/5/2019"],
  "Group C",
  ["3/3/2020", "5/7/2020", "25/7/2020"],
];
const mangledData = [];
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
  mangledData.push({header: data[i], values: data[i + 1]});
}

return mangledData.map(({header, values}) => (
  <div key={header}>
    <h1>{header}</h1>
    <ul>{values.map((v, i) => <li key={i}>{v}</li>))}</ul>
  </div>
));
```

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yes, good catch. I was in Python land. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to render directly your data or you could clean it up first then render as suggested already.

```
export default function App() {
  const groups = [
    "Group A",
    ["10/7/2020", "15/7/2020"],
    "Group B",
    ["5/5/2019"],
    "Group C",
    ["3/3/2020", "5/7/2020", "25/7/2020"]
  ];

  return (
    <>
      {groups.reduce((acc, item) => {
        if (typeof item === "string") {
          acc.push(<span key={item}> {item} </span>);
        } else {
          acc.push(
            <ul>
              {item.map((data, index) => (
                <li key={index}> {data} </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          );
        }
        return acc;
      }, [])}
    </>
  );
}
```

Note that react can render an array, like bellow, that's why the accumilator in my reduce function is an array.

```
export default function App() {
  return (['tuna', ' ','salad']);
}
```